# jquery on() for multiple element and multiple function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner in jquery or javascript. And I'm wondering is there anyway to write a click event for multiple elements and multiple function.

For example, I have a lot of buttons that will execute different function when clicked.
Is there anyway to include all the function in 1 click event? Like "document on click", "button1" will do "function ...", "button2" will do "function ...".

More like a switch case styled ??

Comment: then you need to define each function separately and you can have data attribute to each button element, next you can work one click event handler for all buttons

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeGarchagudashvili for you prompt reply, I did found 1 similar answer, [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/different-way-of-writing-multiple-click-functions), is that what you means??

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Nice discovery ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do that, yes, but it wouldn't be best practice. It would look something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    switch (this.id) { // (Or whatever you want to use to differentiate the buttons)
        case "button1":
            // Do button1's stuff
            // ...
            break;
        case "button2":
            // Do button2's stuff
            // ...
            break;
        // ...and so on...
    }
});
```

But it's much better to use separate handlers. They can still be delegated if you're adding and removing buttons dynamically:

```
$(document)
    .on("click", "#button1", function() { // Again, it doesn't have to be an id...
        // button1's stuff here
    })
    .on("click", "#button2", function() { // ...just whatever differentiates the buttons
        // button2's stuff here
    });
```

Comment: And if elements are static on page, `$("#button1").on("click", function() {` inside `document.ready` will be even more better.

Comment: @Regent, Isn't it will make 1 event handler for each button ?

Comment: @mok_ku yes, this is what is all about: either `switch-case` or multiple event handlers.